# R data splitting unicodes

Tags: r

I have a data and want to split into columns

```
price_list <- c("Vegetables", " Garlic Desi<U+062A><U+06BE><U+0648><U+0645>  <U+062F><U+06CC><U+0633><U+06CC>  140 per kg ", 
     " Fresh-bean<U+0641><U+0631><U+0627><U+0634><U+0628><U+06CC><U+0646>  — per kg ", 
    "Fruits",
    " Apple Kala Kolu Irani<U+0633><U+06CC><U+0628> <U+06A9><U+0627><U+0644><U+0627> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+0644><U+0648> <U+0627><U+06CC><U+0631><U+0627><U+0646><U+06CC>  168 per kg ", 
    " Apple golden  115 per kg ", 
    " Banana (I)<U+06A9><U+06CC><U+0644><U+0627> <U+0627><U+0646><U+0688><U+06CC><U+0646>  182 per dozen ", 
     "Others", 
    " Chicken<U+0645><U+0631><U+063A><U+06CC> <U+0634><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0631>  170 per kg ", 
    " Egg<U+0627><U+0646><U+0688><U+06D2> <U+0634><U+06CC><U+0648><U+0631>  95 per dozen "
    )
```

tried but Unicodes creating problem

```
library(stringr)
    regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"
    rprice <- str_extract(df$price_list, regexp)
    df$price <- data.frame(rprice)
```

Desired out put like

```
    Name      Unicode      Price     Quantity
Vegetables
Fresh-bean    فراشبین       NA       kg
Fruits
Apple golden     NA         115      kg
Others
Egg         انڈے شیور       NA       dozen
```

This forum is really helpful saved hundred and thousands of hours thanks

```
url <- "https://ictadministration.gov.pk/services/price-list/
```

complete code

```
library(rvest)

scraping_wiki <- read_html("https://ictadministration.gov.pk/services/price-list/")


library(magrittr)

price_date <- scraping_wiki %>%
  html_nodes(".tm-article-content > ol:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)") %>% 
  html_text()%>% 
  strsplit(split = "\n") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  .[. != ""]

price_date <- gsub(":", "", price_date)


price_list <- scraping_wiki %>%
  html_nodes(".xl-tbl") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  strsplit(split = "\n") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  .[. != ""]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, messy. This gets you close:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
unis <- price_list %>% str_extract(pattern = "<[[:print:]]*>")
words <- price_list %>% str_extract(pattern = "[A-Z a-z<]*") %>% gsub("<U", "", x = .)
price <- price_list %>% str_extract(pattern = "[0-9]* per") %>% gsub("per", "", x = .)
quant <- price_list %>% str_extract(pattern = "per [a-z]*")
df <- tibble(Name = words, Unicode = unis, Price = price, Quantity = quant)
```

Result:

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Name                     Unicode                                                                Price Quantity
  <chr>                    <chr>                                                                  <chr> <chr>   
1 Vegetables               NA                                                                     NA    NA      
2 " Garlic Desi"           <U+062A><U+06BE><U+0648><U+0645>  <U+062F><U+06CC><U+0633><U+06CC>     "140~ per kg  
3 " Fresh"                 <U+0641><U+0631><U+0627><U+0634><U+0628><U+06CC><U+0646>               " "   per kg  
4 Fruits                   NA                                                                     NA    NA      
5 " Apple Kala Kolu Irani" <U+0633><U+06CC><U+0628> <U+06A9><U+0627><U+0644><U+0627> <U+06A9><U+~ "168~ per kg  
6 " Apple golden  "        NA                                                                     "115~ per kg
```

I'm not a regex genius, so I'm sure there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: you are regex genius, i tried but end up posting here still searching for better solution because it just shows the unicode not the text

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional approach. It's always good to learn to find a work around with functions.

Following are the steps:
1. Clean the price_list and keep the name, number and quantity.
2. Write functions which does that.
3. Apply functions on the new data frame.

```
# clean text
clean_list <- lapply(price_list, function(i) gsub("<[^>]+>", "",i))
clean_list <- lapply(clean_list, function(i) gsub('per','',i))
clean_list <- lapply(clean_list, str_trim)

# convert list to data frame
df <- data.table(do.call('rbind', clean_list))
colnames(df) <- 'text'

# helper functions
get_number <- function(j)
{
    p1 <- unlist(strsplit(j, '  '))
    p2 <- grepl('\\d+',p1)

    if(sum(as.integer(p2)) ==1) return (grep('\\d+',p1,value = T))
    else return (0)

}

get_quantity <- function(j)
{
    p1 <- unlist(strsplit(j, '  '))
    p2 <- grepl('kg|dozen',p1)

    if(sum(as.integer(p2)) ==1) return (grep('kg|dozen',p1,value = T))
    else return (NA)

}

# apply functions and get output
df[,Name := sapply(text, function(i) unlist(strsplit(i, '  '))[1])]
df[,Price := sapply(text, get_number)]
df[,Quantity := sapply(text, get_quantity)]
df[,Unicode := sapply(price_list, function(x) str_extract(string = x, pattern = '<[[:print:]]*>'))]

head(df)
  text                              Name                  Price  Quantity Unicode                                                                             

1 Vegetables                        Vegetables            0      NA       NA                                                                                  
2 Garlic Desi    140  kg            Garlic Desi           140    kg       <U+062A><U+06BE><U+0648><U+0645>  <U+062F><U+06CC><U+0633><U+06CC>                  
3 Fresh-bean  —  kg                 Fresh-bean            0      kg       <U+0641><U+0631><U+0627><U+0634><U+0628><U+06CC><U+0646>                            
4 Fruits                            Fruits                0      NA       NA                                                                                  
5 Apple Kala Kolu Irani     168  kg Apple Kala Kolu Irani 168    kg       <U+0633><U+06CC><U+0628> <U+06A9><U+0627><U+0644><U+0627> <U+06A9><U+0648><U+0644><…
6 Apple golden  115  kg             Apple golden          115    kg       NA                                                                                  
>
```

Comment: wow  i really appreciate your work and approach but why can't i see text other than the Unicode ??