# Origin and name of HTML tag alike unicode numbers within less-than greater-than characters

Tags: unicode, codepoint

I sometimes see unicode numbers that look like

```
<U+062A>
```

Where do they come from and what is the official name of this representation?

Comment: I've never seen that. Example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48988273/4468078 :-) It must be the result of some kind of parsing...

Comment: why do you think it's an HTML tag?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I am quite sure it is not an HTML tag, but it looks similar